# How to write data with FileOutputStream without losing old data?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

If you work with `FileOutputStream` methods, each time you write your file through this methods you've been lost your old data. Is it possible to write file without losing your old data via `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: If you are wondering how you could have worked this out for yourself, you could have read the Javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: [OutputStreamWriter is used instead of FileOutputStream][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320070/appending-a-string-to-an-existing-file-using-outputstreamwriter/23320195?noredirect=1#comment35707473_23320195

Comment: @PeterLawrey to learn by ourself, one usually simply ask internet. And SO is the 1st result before the java doc :-)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Use the constructor that takes a `File` and a `boolean`

```
FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
```

and set the boolean to `true`. That way, the data you write will be appended to the end of the file, rather than overwriting what was already there.

Answer (score 22):

Use the constructor for appending material to the file:

```
FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File object.
```

So to append to a file say "abc.txt" use

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File("abc.txt"),true);
```