# Can't write to file in Android

Tags: java, android, file

This following code snippet seems to create a file successfully, and the `writeData` function writes to the `StringWriter` appropriately, however the file seems to be empty..

```
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);

if(!selectedFile.exists())
    selectedFile.createNewFile();


StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
serializer.setOutput(writer);

Log.i(TAG, "- Output is asigned to the special Serializer object");     

/* The target data is written to the a string buffer in the StringWriter */
writeData(serializer, templateData); 

Log.i(TAG, String.format("- New file Data written: %s", writer.toString())); // Logcat prints the file data from this string beautifully..      

fileOutputStream.write(writer.toString().getBytes()); // Not happening?! Why :(
fileOutputStream.close();
```

The String is definately not empty!

The file created however, is empty! I've also tried variations with `OuputStreamWriter` and the like but the file is not written into. Why? I am testing this on a Nexus 7 tablet and I have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission set.

Update:
All the files are created in this process. The access permission of the file is created as "_rw".

Other methods I've used that give exactly the same result:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(selectedFile.getPath());
fw.write(writer.toString());
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

In all cases, a file is created via createNewFile() however no data is ever written to it. The app carries on as normal without throwing anything. I just don't understand :'(

Comment: I assume the string is not empty.

Comment: Ensure the file is created before creating an `OutputStream` on it.

Comment: The string is not empty!

Comment: No the is flushed in the writeData function, and the appropriate data is written to the StringWriter

Comment: @Alex I have tried it both ways it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Is the file writeable by the userid of your process?  Delete the target file and try again...

Comment: @KeithRandall I don't understand, what does that mean? :S

Comment: If the target file started off as empty and isn't writeable by your process for some reason (probably, owned by another user), then it wouldn't succeed.

Comment: No the all the files are explicitly created in this process! Ill update the question:)

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(selectedFile);//u can use (filename, Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)

if(!selectedFile.exists())
    selectedFile.createNewFile();

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
      osw.append(templateData);
      osw.flush();
      osw.close();
```

Comment: I've also tried this method - doesn't seem to work either! This is so frustrating there must be something bigger going on here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling FileOutputStream.FileOutputStream(File) after you've written to the file all the data will be erased. Check out this thread: [How to write data with FileOutputStream without losing old data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544771/how-to-write-data-with-fileoutputstream-without-losing-old-data)