# Writing in file that already exists - but i have a issue

Tags: java, file

I have a code that should write lines in File.. 
- If file don't exist, it should make new file with that name. 
- If file exist, it should just write new line...

It appears that it always make new file and i cant figure out how to avoid it...
Here is my code...

How to make it just to write new line if file is already there?

Thx for ur time...

```
if (isANumber(value) == true) {
    String valResult = "validation_result=VALID";
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("ValidationResults.txt")));
    System.out.println("Writing in TEXT file: " + "type=" + key + ";value=" +  value + ";" + valResult);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("\ntype=" + key + ";value=" +  value +  valResult + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} else {
    valResult = "validation_result=INVALID";
    BufferedWriter writer =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("ValidationResults.txt")));
    System.out.println("Writing in TEXT file: " + "type=" + key + ";value=" +  value + ";" +  valResult);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("\ntype=" + key + ";value=" +  value + ";" + valResult + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: It will be a good idea to add the language and platform tags to this question.

Comment: You need to open the file in Append(Upate) mode.

Comment: What language do you use? What is the target OS or device? Put this information in question tags to attract more experts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write data with FileOutputStream without losing old data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544771/how-to-write-data-with-fileoutputstream-without-losing-old-data)

Comment: Im sorry, Abizem... i work in java, eclipse...

Comment: You have almost the same code in the two blocks. You can factor this out. The only difference is the value for `valResult`. In addition, whenever you see or think of writing `(x == true)` remember that this will be the same as `x` for any boolean expression `x`. Thus, if `x` is a boolean expression, then the following will all be the same: `x==true`, `(x==true)==true`, `((x==true)==true)==true`. Is it true that it is the case that the truth is that you don't understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User a FileWriter. Thats should solve ur problem. The True parameter says that the next line will append to the existing file. if u use false instead the file would be overridden.

```
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt", true));
```

Comment: TYYYYYY recall :)  works just fine now :) 
I tried that option, but didn't use "true" part :)

Comment: I wish i can vote UP your answer, but i still don't have enough reputation :)