# How to append arraylist<object > in a file in java

Tags: java, arraylist, append, fileoutputstream

the given function writes in file but on calling again it overwrites the previous list object in file eg

if array list index 0 contain name- "aman" and i call this function it saves "aman" in file.
but when for index 1 having name-"lavesh" is called it overwrites on previous data

it is in file like  "lavesh"
but i want it like  "   aman
                        lavesh "

```java
public void alter_file( ArrayList<Flight_registrie> x) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(" Flight Registrie.txt"));
            oos.writeObject(x);
            x.clear();
            oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An I/O error occurs");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

No error is there but my method can be wrong

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but you are not writing to a text file but rather are serializing to a data file. In this situation, it may be better to re-serialize the whole data rather than trying to append to an existing file. Appending works great for a text file, and one way to do this is to use a FileWriter whose second boolean parameter is `true`, but again, that is not what we're talking about here... although FileOutputStream also can take a second boolean parameter that determines if you append or not. Again I'm not sure how safe this is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write data with FileOutputStream without losing old data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544771/how-to-write-data-with-fileoutputstream-without-losing-old-data)

Comment: thanks for sharing the other question i have same issue

Comment: Then fix it as per the answer in the duplicate

Comment: Make sure the **Flight_registrie** class **implements Serializable**. then so as to ***append*** to the file: `ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(" Flight Registrie.txt", true));`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `oos.writeObject(x);` will write a file with the content of `x`. It will remove the content of the old file then.

You can simply avoid this by adding `true` behind the constructor of `FileOutputStream`. The boolean decides whether you want to append to the file or not. Default is that you don't want to append data.