# overwriting to a file its delete everything

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, random

```
String testLine=id+" "+name+" "+NewQuizz;

                Scanner ReadScanner3 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
                FileOutputStream Out=new FileOutputStream("temp.txt");
                PrintWriter pwrite=new PrintWriter(Out);
                while(ReadScanner3.hasNextLine()) {
                      line=ReadScanner3.nextLine();
                    id=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '))) ;



                    pwrite.println(infoAfterModfiy);


                }

                System.out.print("after grade modifcation:");
                String printModfiy=SearchID+"\t\t"+name+"\t\t"+printNewQuizz;
                System.out.println(printModfiy);
                pwrite.close();
                Scanner ReadScanner4 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("temp.txt"));
                FileOutputStream Out2=new FileOutputStream("input.txt");
                PrintWriter pwrite2=new PrintWriter(Out,true);
                while(ReadScanner4.hasNextLine()) {
                    String Line=ReadScanner4.nextLine();
                    pwrite2.println(Line);
                }
                pwrite2.close();

            }
```

hello hope you all good.
I have problem with the overwriting if i changed the quize grade and I display it again it delete everything  in input.txt

sample input

```
91007 Ahmad Said 50.0 
91004 Hassan Khan 45.5 
91003 Suleiman Wasim 72.6 
91002 Majed Sameer 60.0 
91006 Muhammad Adel 85.5 
91005 Muhsim Zuheir 70.0 
91001 Muneeb Abdullatif 30.0
```

Comment: It is good practice to include neat, readable code that would run if someone were to copy/paste it into an IDE - [reprex]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write data with FileOutputStream without losing old data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544771/how-to-write-data-with-fileoutputstream-without-losing-old-data)

Comment: @mypetlion no not really

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see what the problem is. You're outputting to your input file. Look at this line: `FileOutputStream Out2=new FileOutputStream("input.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

I came here a bit late; however, here is what you can do to make your code a little cleaner. The FileOutputStream can be removed along with the additional Scanner and PrintWriter objects to perform what you are trying to achieve.

**consider:**

```
// Just an example 
double[] newGrade = {30.0, 37.0, 55.0, 75.0, 80.0, 90.0, 95.0};
int i = 0;
String outputTxt = "", oldGrade = "";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
PrintWriter writer =new PrintWriter("output.txt");
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    String tmp = "";
    tmp += scan.next();
    tmp += " " + scan.next();
    tmp += " " + scan.next();
    oldGrade = scan.next();
    tmp += " " + oldGrade;

    if (i <= newGrade.length) {
    // Update grade here
    outputTxt += tmp.replace(oldGrade, newGrade[i] + "\r");
    }
    i++;
}
writer.print(outputTxt);
scan.close();
writer.close();
```

input.txt

```
91007 Ahmad Said 50.0 
91004 Hassan Khan 45.5 
91003 Suleiman Wasim 72.6 
91002 Majed Sameer 60.0 
91006 Muhammad Adel 85.5 
91005 Muhsim Zuheir 70.0 
91001 Muneeb Abdullatif 30.0
```

output.txt - grades updated.

```
91007 Ahmad Said 30.0
91004 Hassan Khan 37.0
91003 Suleiman Wasim 55.0
91002 Majed Sameer 75.0
91006 Muhammad Adel 80.0
91005 Muhsim Zuheir 90.0
91001 Muneeb Abdullatif 95.0
```